# Express.JS: how can I set response status by name rather than number?

Tags: node.js, http, express, http-status-codes, magic-numbers

OK, everyone knows 200 is OK and 404 is not found. But I for things like permanent vs temporary redirect, or payment required, or other more exotic HTTP error codes, it might be better to do something like:

```
response.status('REQUEST_ENTITY_TOO_LARGE');
```

Rather than just use a magic number which is generally considered bad practice. I could, of course, have 413:'REQUEST_ENTITY_TOO_LARGE' in some object, but Express already has a copy of the status code -> name mappings and I'd rather not duplicate that.

How can I specify a response status by name in Express JS?

**Edit**: thanks @Akshat for pointing out http.STATUS_CODES. Elaborating on his answer, since the values are themselves unique, one can run:

```
   var statusCodeByName = {};
   for ( var number in http.STATUS_CODES ) {
     statusCodeByName[http.STATUS_CODES[number]] = number
   }
```

Which allows one to:

```
  > statusCodeByName['Request Entity Too Large']
  '413'
```

Comment: Why is it bad to answer with a number? That number is well understood by browsers, if you try not to send it then how could the browser tell the difference between a 404 and a 500 for example?

Comment: @AlbertoZaccagni Obviously we'll need to send a number over the wire, that's required by RFC2616. My interest in being able to specify the status by name (obviously still sending it by number) is for readability.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

There's a Node module just for this purpose: http-status-codes.

https://www.npmjs.org/package/http-status-codes

Here's what the documentation says:

**Installation**

`npm install http-status-codes`

**Usage**

```
var HttpStatus = require('http-status-codes');

response.send(HttpStatus.OK);
response.send(
    HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, 
    { error: HttpStatus.getStatusText(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR) }
);
```

Answer (score 2):

HTTP response codes are not magic numbers; they are the spec. The descriptive text is just a helpful reminder, but the protocol itself relies on those status codes, and the core ones are very worth learning. Two thoughts. You can certainly create a constant at the top of your file and do this:

```
var REQUEST_ENTITY_TOO_LARGE = 413;
response.status(REQUEST_ENTITY_TOO_LARGE);
```

However, most REST APIs just implement the following responses:

```
200 - OK
201 - Created  # Response to successful POST or PUT
302 - Found # Temporary redirect such as to /login
303 - See Other # Redirect back to page after successful login
304 - Not Modified
400 - Bad Request
401 - Unauthorized  # Not logged in
403 - Forbidden  # Accessing another user's resource
404 - Not Found
500 - Internal Server Error
```

Finally, in case it's helpful, I'll share our code for rendering custom error pages:

```
module.exports = function(app) {

  app.use(function(req, res) {
  // curl https://localhost:4000/notfound -vk
  // curl https://localhost:4000/notfound -vkH "Accept: application/json"
    res.status(404);

    if (req.accepts('html')) {
      res.render('error/404', { title:'404: Page not found', error: '404: Page not found', url: req.url });
      return;
    }

    if (req.accepts('json')) {
      res.send({ title: '404: Page not found', error: '404: Page not found', url: req.url });
    }
  });

  app.use( function(err, req, res, next) {
    // curl https://localhost:4000/error/403 -vk
    // curl https://localhost:4000/error/403 -vkH "Accept: application/json"
    var statusCode = err.status || 500;
    var statusText = '';
    var errorDetail = (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') ? 'Sorry about this error' : err.stack;

    switch (statusCode) {
    case 400:
      statusText = 'Bad Request';
      break;
    case 401:
      statusText = 'Unauthorized';
      break;
    case 403:
      statusText = 'Forbidden';
      break;
    case 500:
      statusText = 'Internal Server Error';
      break;
    }

    res.status(statusCode);

    if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production' && process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'test') {
      console.log(errorDetail);
    }

    if (req.accepts('html')) {
      res.render('error/500', { title: statusCode + ': ' + statusText, error: errorDetail, url: req.url });
      return;
    }

    if (req.accepts('json')) {
      res.send({ title: statusCode + ': ' + statusText, error: errorDetail, url: req.url });
    }
  });
};
```

Comment: A magic number is any number that appears in code without a name (generally excluding 0 and 1) - see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)#Unnamed_numerical_constants. The 'descriptive text' is actually part of the spec - see RFC2616 at http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html. Additionally, rather than focusing on which status codes are popular, it's better to focus on which status codes are *correct*.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible unless you are willing to change the source code yourself. Take a look at the [implementation](https://github.com/visionmedia/express/blob/master/lib/response.js#L80) of `res.send`

If you provide a string as an argument it just interprets it as html and sends the response as 200.

I think the reason express uses numbers for HTTP status codes is because node itself uses numbers as object keys for [http.STATUS_CODES](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_status_codes)

Comment: Thanks. http.STATUS_CODES is what I was looking for - since the values aren't duplicated, you could conceivably create a clone with inverted key<->values and use that.

Comment: `node --print "JSON.stringify(Object.entries(http.STATUS_CODES).reduce((acc, [key, value]) => (acc[value.replace(/ /g, '_')] = key, acc), {}))" | jq '.'`